# A Domino Rectangle

Tags: dominoes, packing

Can you arrange a standard set of $28$ dominoes into a rectangle of $7\times8$, where each of the 8 rows sum to $21$ and each of the 7 columns sum to $24$?

[image: double 6 dominoes]

<sub>Image from [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes#Tiles_and_suits).</sub>

Or, alternatively, pack the dominoes into their $7\times4\times2$ box, with equal rows and stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known problem which has been solved. One of the solutions is described in the following paper by Michael Springfield and Wayne Goddard:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6923/5113e24d2bb602513410b717fda5ef16ef35.pdf

Here is the domino arrangement from this paper (it is 7x8, rotate it to get 8x7):

> [image]